# What's the purpose of np_utils.to_categorical() in keras?

Tags: keras

Hello I'm training my self in sentiment recognition using audio file and a code from a  repository of git.

Code sample:

```
newdf1 = np.random.rand(len(rnewdf)) < 0.8
train = rnewdf[newdf1]
test = rnewdf[~newdf1]

trainfeatures = train.iloc[:, :-1]

trainlabel = train.iloc[:, -1:]

testfeatures = test.iloc[:, :-1]

testlabel = test.iloc[:, -1:]

from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X_train = np.array(trainfeatures)
y_train = np.array(trainlabel)
X_test = np.array(testfeatures)
y_test = np.array(testlabel)

lb = LabelEncoder()

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_train))
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_test))
```

I'd like to understand what's this code do.

```
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_train))
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(y_test))
```

I ask this question because in training phase of the CNN, I've got an error in `model.fit`
 Error when checking target: expected activation_26 to have shape (1,)...

understand this may help me to overcome the problem.

thanks

Comment: You should better describe the problem you have, instead of asking about your solution. This is an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks, can you the explain me the what does np_utils.to_categorical() ?